# Get built entry from webpack on compiler instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

My webpack entry is a javascript function that takes some arguments. I am working with webpack dev middleware and the webpack 4 node api

In dev mode, i'd like the application and its assets to be served from memory. However, the entry for my compilation is a function, which id like to use inside of my non webpack code like so:

```
// start-server-build.js
const done = (compiler) => {
  // getCompiledEntry does not exist on webpack compiler instance
  // but im hoping it demonstrates my goals 
  const nodeServerBuild = compiler.getCompiledEntry()
  return nodeServerBuild(arg1, arg2)
}

webpackDevMiddleware.waitUntilValid(() => done(compiler))
```

Here is a more complete example:

https://gist.github.com/lfender6445/e25dfdaac8a19ea41de5f79617e4b6c2#file-start-server-js-L34

Is it possible to compile my webpack entry and return the compiled function from the compiler instance or by some other means and is it possible to do this without writing to the file system?

I have read over the documentation for webpack node API but nothing sticks out

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware
- https://webpack.js.org/api/node/

Comment: Hi! did you figure out the issue. I currently have the similar issue. In production mode, I run `webpack([configProdClient, configProdServer]).run((error, stats) => {}` but it is not compiling the entry point to the output path.

Comment: i never did sort it out sorry @Yilmaz

Comment: I figured out last night. Thank you for reply!

Comment: would you plz consider adding your solution as an answer?